# Hadoop example application hangs on Windows single node

Tags: hadoop, windows-10, hadoop-yarn

I have installed single node Hadoop on Windows and it is apprently working.

Unfortunately, I can't run test application on it.

When I do

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.9.0.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

as described on it's page, I get it not returning to command prompt. On referenced job page I see

> YarnApplicationState: ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be
>   allocated, launched and register with RM.
>
> `Diagnostics: [Mon Apr 23 00:46:44 +0300 2018] Application is added to
>   the scheduler and is not yet activated. Skipping AM assignment as
>   cluster resource is empty. Details : AM Partition =
>   <DEFAULT_PARTITION>; AM Resource Request = <memory:2048, vCores:1>;
>   Queue Resource Limit for AM = <memory:0, vCores:0>; User AM Resource
>   Limit of the queue = <memory:0, vCores:0>; Queue AM Resource Usage =
>   <memory:0, vCores:0>;`

What does it mean and how to push it?

Comment: Your queue apparently is configured with no resources... Is an active  NodeManager running?

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry not sure about the terms, can you ask in more simple words

Comment: NodeManagers run the code. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeManager.html  ... In the output shown, `Limit of the queue = <memory:0, vCores:0>` looks like you have no available resources allocated for a job, meaning no active `NodeManager` running (see `jps` command) and/or run `start-yarn.sh`